# Pass message headers when calling client methods over SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr, azure-signalr

I'm using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.IHubClients` to obtain an `IClientProxy` to call methods on connected clients.

The received messages are processed client-side using an implementation of the `TryParseMessage` method on `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocol.IHubProtocol` interface.

I've adapted the default implementations of `IHubProtocol` to include some additional processing of any headers sent with the message e.g. to flow relevant context from the hub to the connected clients.

```
public bool TryParseMessage(ref ReadOnlySequence<byte> input, IInvocationBinder binder, out HubMessage message)
{
    if (!_innerProtocol.TryParseMessage(ref input, binder, out message))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (message is HubInvocationMessage invocationMessage)
    {
        IDictionary<string, string> headers = invocationMessage.Headers;
        // Do something with headers
    }

    return true;
}
```

I can't find any way to populate those message headers, however, when invoking client methods from the hub (at least not with `IClientProxy` because `IHubProtocol.WriteMessage` does not seem to be invoked by the library with that approach). Access to the headers hub-side seems to be quite private, so is there any way to solve this?